# How to disable dead code analysis for preprocessor?

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

How to disable dead code analysis for preprocessor? Our project has some macro magic, which Android Studio doesn't understand. Code is grayed out where is shouldn't be.

```
#if SOMETHING
// Here code is gray, but it shouldn't be.
#else
....
#endif
```

One more solid example is this. It doesn't gray out only for `__arch64__`, but project compiles for all architectures.

```
#if defined(__x86_64__)
        .. // x64 specific
#elif defined(__i386__)
        .. // RIP: x86_64 specific
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
        .. // etc..
#endif
```

Another solid example is this trick. We have `unity_build.cpp` file where all transition units all included. There is preprocessor magic in every transition unit.

```
#ifndef MYPROJ_UNITY_BUILD
... // Transition unit code.
#endif
```

And in `unity_build.cpp`

```
#ifdef MYPROJ_UNITY_BUILD
    #undef MYPROJ_UNITY_BUILD
#else
    #define MYPROJ_UNITY_BUILD 1
#endif
#include "first-transition-unit.cpp"
#include "second-transition-unit.cpp"
```

Android Studio grays out code in every transition unit.

Comment: your preprocessor will know if `SOMETHING` is defined or not, though I also dont know the name of the component resopnsible for graying out the code

Comment: @user463035818 Clang compiles everything how it should compile, but Android Studio grays code out, where it shouldn't. Preprocessor works, like it should work. IMHO It is definitely problem with IDE.

Comment: yes thats more or less what i was saying, its not the preprocessor, but something in your IDE

Comment: ah now I think I do understand what you mean in the question. You want to disable (not at the preprocessor but in your IDE) dead code analysis for macros (which are processed correctly by the preprocessor). Sorry, my misunderstanding

Comment: funny that SO foramtting seems to gray out in the same way as your IDE does ;). Are you sure `SOMETHING` is defined when you reach the `#if SOMETHING` ?

Comment: @user463035818 Yes. I don't really care about this Android Studio feature, I really like to turn it off.

Comment: The question is really all about Android Studio, and not really about C++ (just incidentally about C++, since that's the code being used in Android Studio).